# Convert rows with multiple attributes into rows with one attribute per row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, unpivot

I have a table in the following form:

```
Id    |   Arrival  |  Departure | Expected Return
-------------------------------------------------
1     | 2019/8/2   | 2019/8/10  | 2019/8/15
2     | 2019/8/1   | 2019/8/15  | 2019/8/22
3     | 2019/8/2   | 2019/8/16  | 2019/8/21
```

however, I would need a query that returns something like this (ideally without defining additional functions)

```
Id    |   Action        |  Date
--------------------------------------
1     | Arrival         | 2019/8/2   
1     | Departure       | 2019/8/10  
1     | Expected Return | 2019/8/15
2     | Arrival         | 2019/8/1   
2     | Departure       | 2019/8/15  
2     | Expected Return | 2019/8/22
3     | Arrival         | 2019/8/2   
3     | Departure       | 2019/8/16  
3     | Expected Return | 2019/8/21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UNION ALL:

```
select Id, 'Arrival' "Action", Arrival Date from tablename
union all
select Id, 'Departure' "Action", Departure Date from tablename
union all
select Id, 'Expected Return' "Action", "Expected Return" Date from tablename
order by Id, Date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTD6oDaweiVYXwG3D54P5m/0).
Results:

```
| id  | Action          | date       |
| --- | --------------- | -----------|
| 1   | Arrival         | 2019-08-02 |
| 1   | Departure       | 2019-08-10 |
| 1   | Expected Return | 2019-08-15 |
| 2   | Arrival         | 2019-08-01 |
| 2   | Departure       | 2019-08-15 |
| 2   | Expected Return | 2019-08-22 |
| 3   | Arrival         | 2019-08-02 |
| 3   | Departure       | 2019-08-16 |
| 3   | Expected Return | 2019-08-21 |
```

Edit.
Using [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html) ... `VALUES` could be more efficient (although not simpler):

```
select t.id, v.*
from tablename t, 
  lateral (values
    ('Arrival', t.Arrival),
    ('Departure', t.Departure),
    ('Expected Return', t."Expected Return")
   ) v (Action, Date);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTD6oDaweiVYXwG3D54P5m/1).

Comment: sh*t!... clever approach, did't come to mind. Will test and let you know.

Comment: it works perfectly, just wondering if there is a way of making it more efficiently

Comment: many thanks for your time. This is what I was trying to figure out before I gut surprised with the simplicity of your initial approach. This is good, although, honestly it is hard to me to understand.

Comment: Lateral joins are not easy to grasp, this is why I posted the link to the documentation but you can find more if you google it. If you find the 1st query efficient use it, because it is more readable and maintainable.